# Furniture plinth on carpet - making it level

Tags: furniture, level, leveling

I am planning some wardobes and would like to create a plinth for the carcasses to sit on.

This plinth would sit upon a relatively freshly carpeted area and my concern is that this may hinder my ability to get the base level.

What can I do here?

[image]

Am I wasting my time trying to level this on carpet? Should I try something more aking to how IKEA Pax is put together? This might put more pressure in a smaller area to level carpet? But this again may not be 100% level, as the Pax system still comes with feet to help level after being placed...

[image]

Comment: Enlist an adult-sized person or a couple of sacks of concrete to weight the plinth while shimming.

Comment: Good advice! While building another plinth I placed a spirit level across and then stood on the plinth over the level.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've installed all my furniture on carpet in a 125 year old house with *very* uneven floors.

Simply shim as required to get your furniture level. I usually install wood shims under each foot (sometimes more than one per foot) and tap them in as necessary to level the item. I've also installed some IKEA cabinets that use a screw-adjuster foot for leveling. In some places, I've had to shim under the foot to get it level.

It looks like you have an advantage of a separate base onto which you're installing the cabinet. If you want, you can shim between the base and the cabinet, or, you can just drive the shim under the cabinet base on top of the carpet.

When you put the shims in, you'll compress the carpet & pad in that area, but you're compressing it everywhere anyway. As the whole thing sits there, it *should* settle fairly evenly into the carpet, retaining its level installation. This *may* depend on how evenly the furniture item is loaded - if it's a dresser with heavy sweaters on one side & silk blouses on the other, it may settle unevenly. If, in the future, you ever notice that it looks uneven, just grab the level and a pack of shims and relevel it then.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. It is going to be a wardrobe, so will (hopefully) be evenly loaded. I recently added a plinth underneath a new media unit made from IKEA Besta units which led to a bit of a headache of levelling, hence me asking this question. Thankfully I could reuse the levelling feet that came with the Besta units haha.